# Style <li> to not show disc "ball"

Tags: html

I'm using the `li` tag for my menu but it keeps showing the disc ball `<li>` even though I don't have it in my html...

How can I get rid of it? I looked on google but I can't find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Any more details? Any code? disc ball? etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS:

```
li { list-style: none; }
```

.